# CLLocation distance is not accurate

Tags: ios, mkmapview, cllocation, gmsmapview

I'm using GMSMapView for iOS app in which a list of data is retrieved using an API and their distance will be displayed as a part of UITableView cell using CLLocation distancefromlocation. But, the problem is the result is not accurate as the Google map's route based distance. How can I get the route based distance ? I tried using MKMapRoute distance property and it takes some delay to load and it returns 0.

Comment: are you using a phone to test your app? or just the simulator? .. sometimes the simulator gives false location because of the internet connection..

Comment: I'm using both iPad and iPod

Comment: I'm getting result. For example, from Location 1 to location 2, the actual distance is 470kms. But, it shows 740 kms.